# Verifying uniqueness of Playfairs axiom in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: geometry

I have been asked to verify that $\mathbb{R^2}$ satisfys the axioms of incidence and playfairs axiom. i have show $I_1 ,I_2, I_3 $ And need so to show Playfairs axiom.

Playfairs axiom: For every line L and every point A there exists a unique line M containing A and parallel to L.

(Case1) To start if A is on L clearly the existence of such a line is satisfied as L is parallel to L and A is on it. the uniqueness im a bit fuzzy on.

(Case2i) A is not on L and L is a line of the form L=mx+b for a fixed m and b and all real values x. $A=(a_1,a_2) $ then the line $L'=m(x+a_1)+b+a_2 $ passes through A and is parrelle to the given line.

(Case2ii) A is not on L and L is of the form $x=c$ then we have that $A=(a_1,a_2) $ if we take the line $x=a_1 $ is parallel to the given line and passes through $a_2$

i know that i somehow need to show that the lines are unique i have show for any given line and any given point that there is a line parallel to A that passes through it but i havent shown that there is only one such line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is not in $L$, write the equation of $L$ as $a\cdot v+b=0$. Then the line $a\cdot v-a\cdot A=0$ passes through $A$ and is parallel to $L$.

Assume there is another line passing through $A$ and parallel to $L$. Its equation should be $a\cdot v+c=0$. Since $A$ is in that line we must have $a\cdot A+c=0$. Therefore $c=-a\cdot A$. We conclude that it is the same line as before.